# Retrieving Magento Sub Category Name and Link

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

So on the product view page I wanted to create a link that says something to the extent of 'View All Sub Category Products' 
I know the general place where I need to make the edit in 
/app/design/frontend/default/{my theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

However I am not sure on how to retrieve the product's sub category name and link

Comment: when you say product subcategory is it actually category for product but as that category has some parent category so you are saying it as subcategory do comment

Comment: Yes that is correct. This is my site and an example https://vetmedusa.com/forceps/adson-dressing-forceps/adson-dressing-forceps-4-75-german.html If you look on the top you can see Home / Forceps / Adson Dressing Forceps / Adson Dressing Forceps 4.75" German   I want to include a link on the product page that says 'View All Adson Dressing Forceps' for a lot of people the navigation menu is easily missed so I wanted to add it to the product page to make it more centralized with the rest of the information

Answer (score 0):

$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

echo $_category->getURL()

This set of code will get category for you.

use getName to get name of category.

further added:
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
    echo $_cat->getUrl();
}

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work. I got this error>

"Fatal error: Call to a member function getURL() on a non-object in /home/vetmedus/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/surgical/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 87"

I was using this      

<?php 
  $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
  $theurl = $_category->getURL();
  $thename = $_category->getName();
  ?>View All <a href=<?php echo $theurl; ?>><?php echo $thename; ?> </a>

Comment: echo $_category->debug()  and check what is being displayed